# Overriding unapply method

Tags: scala

I have a **case** from a library class and I want to override `unapply` method **to reduce the number of parameters** I need to pass to do pattern matching against it. I do this:

```
object ws1 {
  // a library class
  case class MyClass(a: Int, b: String, c: String, d: Double /* and many more ones*/)

  // my object I created to override unapply of class MyClass
  object MyClass {
    def unapply(x: Int) = Some(x)
  }

  val a = new MyClass(1, "2", "3", 55.0 /* and many more ones*/)
  a match {
    case MyClass(x /*only the first one is vital*/) => x  // java.io.Serializable = (1,2,3,55.0)
    case _ => "no"
  }
}
```

But I want it to return just `1`. What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
case class MyClass(a: Int, b: String, c: String, d: Double /* and many more ones*/)
object MyClassA {
   def unapply(x: MyClass) = Some(x.a)
}

val a = new MyClass(1, "2", "3", 55.0 /* and many more ones*/)

a match {
    case MyClassA(2) => ??? // does not match
    case MyClassA(1) => a   // matches
    case _ => ??? 
}
```

You cannot define your custom `unapply` method in the `MyClass` object, because it would have to take a `MyClass` parameter, and there's already one such method there – one generated automatically for the case class. Therefore you have to define it in a different object (`MyClassA` in this case).

Pattern matching in Scala takes your object and applies several `unapply` and `unapplySeq` methods to it until it gets `Some` with values that match the ones specified in the pattern.
`MyClassA(1)` matches `a` if `MyClassA.unapply(a) == Some(1)`.

Note: if I wrote `case m @ MyClassA(1) =>`, then the `m` variable would be of type `MyClass`.

Edit:

```
a match {
    case MyClassA(x) => x  // x is an Int, equal to a.a
    case _ => ??? 
}
```

Comment: why does it return Any in case of a or d?

Comment: Could you post a snippet that causes the problem?

Comment: @Grienders It returns Any because of your default case, which specifies a return value of "no". Since one case returns Int and the other String, the nearest common superclass for the result of the match is Any.

Comment: @Shadowlands, why does b return String?

Comment: I actually have a more complex class hierachy. I did all I needed to do. But it complayns `wrong number of arguments for pattern MyClass(a: Int, b: String, c: String, d: Double /* and many more ones*/)`. Everything is imported, I even imported method unapply of MyClassA, but there is no luck yet. 

Do you have any idea why?

Comment: It's too big to post it.

Comment: Just to be sure: you're writing `case MyClassA(a)` or `case MyClass(a)`? The former should work, the latter won't.

Comment: @Grienders If by 'b' you mean your code `case _ => "no"` (which is what I was referring to), all case statements return their last calculated value, and the match as a whole returns a value that is of a type compatible with all of its cases. I suggest doing a search or asking a new question to find out more.

Answer (score 1):

I would ditch the overloaded unapply and just use the following for the match:

```
a match {
  case MyClass(x, _, _, _) => x  // Result is: 1
  case _ => "no"
}
```

**EDIT :**

If you really want to avoid the extra underscores, I think you'll need to look at something like:

```
a match {
  case x:MyClass => x.a
  case _ => "no"
}
```

Comment: This is want I do not want to do, that's why I decided to override unapply.

Comment: Why do you not want this? What about it doesn't work for you?

Comment: what if x is Seq or List, I'd have to do pattern matching again?

Comment: Do you mean that x is a List rather than a MyClass? In that case, there are specific patterns for handling Lists, using `::`. If you want (only) the first element of a List, if it exists, match against: `case x :: theRest => x`