# Custom extractor of case class is not working in pattern matching

Tags: scala

Consider a case class Person

```
case class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String, middleName: Option[String])

object Person {

def apply(firstName: String, lastName: String): Person = new Person(firstName, lastName, None)

def unapply(arg: Person): Option[(String, String)] = Some(arg.firstName, arg.lastName)
}

 val person = Person("firstName", "lastName")

 person match {
case Person(firstName, lastName) => Console.println(firstName + " " + lastName)
}
```

In pattern matching with a case class compiler gives me an error: wrong number of arguments in pattern matching but when I use a class instead of case class then its working.

```
class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String, middleName: Option[String])
```

What I understand here is that we can not use own custom extractor for case class but can use own constructors(apply). Please explain me this weird behavior.

Here is a ScalaFiddle to test that: [https://scalafiddle.io/sf/HvxvdAZ/0](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/HvxvdAZ/1)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848839/overriding-unapply-method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your custom `unapply` conflicts with the auto-generated `unapply` because it has the same name and the same argument types (only the return type is different). So, this is invalid for the same reason as

```
class A {
  def u(i: Int): Int = i
  def u(i: Int): String = "int" + i
}
```

would be invalid. This code snippet would give the error:

> error: method u is defined twice;
>     the conflicting method u was defined at line 12:7

Therefore, you either have to define a separate extractor object with its own `unapply` (something like `object FirstLast { def unapply(...) ... }`), or omit the `case` in the class declaration.

**Separate extractor object**

Here is one (in my opinion relatively elegant) way to do it:

```
case class Person(
  firstName: String, 
  lastName: String, 
  middleName: Option[String]
)

object Person {

  def apply(
    firstName: String, 
    lastName: String
  ): Person = new Person(firstName, lastName, None)

  object FirstLast {
    def unapply(arg: Person): Option[(String, String)] = 
      Some((arg.firstName, arg.lastName))
  }
}

val person = Person("firstName", "lastName")
person match {
  case Person.FirstLast(firstName, lastName) => 
    Console.println(firstName + " " + lastName)
}
```

---

**Omitting `case`, implementing your own `unapply`**

If you want to completely replace the original `unapply`, then you could do this:

```
class Person(
  val firstName: String, 
  val lastName: String, 
  val middleName: Option[String]
)

object Person {

  def apply(
    firstName: String, 
    lastName: String, 
    middleName: Option[String]
  ): Person = new Person(firstName, lastName, middleName)

  def apply(
    firstName: String, 
    lastName: String
  ): Person = new Person(firstName, lastName, None)

  def unapply(arg: Person): Option[(String, String)] = 
    Some((arg.firstName, arg.lastName))
}

val person = Person("firstName", "lastName")
person match {
  case Person(firstName, lastName) => 
    Console.println(firstName + " " + lastName)
}
```

but again, it allows for only one single `unapply`. Use a separate extractor to have more than one `unapply` methods.

Answer (score 0):

It is not what you asked, but here is what you can do if you want to keep your `case class`:

`case Person(firstName, lastName, _) =>`

Add an underscore `_` for each parameter that you don't use.

See https://scalafiddle.io/sf/HvxvdAZ/3